# UIView added to UIApplication.shared.keyWindow in iOS 10 is not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios10, hoko

I have been banging my head against the wall with this issue, but since I updated to **iOS 10.1**, any view added to `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` does not seem to render. It is simply invisible.

I happen to have a test phone with **iOS 9.3.2** running in it and the added views DO appear visible.

NB: I have been using this for a long time to show "in app notifications" and it has been working like a charm.

It is a **VERY** simple piece of code and does not throw any errors whatsoever.

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))

view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow

window?.addSubview(view)
```

I have checked the following:

the window is not nil and has a perfectly valid frame.
Same goes for the UIView I add, and it does appear in the view hierarchy.
I have also tried moving the code around, putting it in ViewDidAppear, ViewDidLayoutSubViews etc… but to no avail.

Any ideas? Anybody else facing the same issue?

**EDIT**: 
Seeing some of the comments below, I believe I need to clarify: this piece of code *should work* (if I take reference on Apple documentation). Also, the issue is **iOS 10 specific**. In versions < iOS 10 it works perfectly.

So I am not looking for ***where*** this called should be called but rather for ***what*** may have changed in iOS 10 that would bring this behaviour.

Thanks

Comment: try adding to rootviewcontroller of window

Comment: Also tried. Also not working in iOS 10 but working in iOS 9.

Comment: have you tried UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: Yes. Also, since I am getting the keyWindow, it is already key ;-) And i should add, this is NOT being called in the AppDelegate, but on a UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Totally by chance I found the solution, and it is very strange.
In our project, we are using HOKO Links for deeplinking and we encountered a bug with iOS 10: HOKO was "stealing" all events in `func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool` (Facebook, Google Sign in…).

We filed a bug to the guys from HOKO and managed to track down the culprit by scanning their code for "version greater than iOS9" and came accross the following method:

```
- (void)requestDeferredDeeplink:(void (^)(NSString *))handler {

    BOOL isFirstRun = ![[HOKUtils     objectForKey:HOKDeferredDeeplinkingNotFirstRun] boolValue];

    if (isFirstRun) {
        self.handler = handler;

#if defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 90000
    if (HOKSystemVersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo(@"9.0")) {

        NSString *fingerprintURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?uid=%@", [HOKNetworkOperation urlFromPath:HOKFingerprintMatchingPath], [HOKDevice device].uid];
        self.safariViewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fingerprintURL]];
        self.safariViewController.delegate = self;

        UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

        UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
        window.alpha = 0;

        [rootViewController presentViewController:self.safariViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self requestDeferredDeeplink];
    }
#else
    [self requestDeferredDeeplink];
#endif
  }
}
```

The solution was to remove all the code between 
`#if defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 90000` and `#endif` and replace with `[self requestDeferredDeeplink];`

We also noticed that **HOKO** was setting the *window alpha to 0…*
And **THAT** is what was preventing `UIViews` added to the `keyWindow` being visible. However, strangely enough, it wasn't effecting the rest of the App.

I doubt anyone else is likely to encounter this issue, but I am leaving this here for posterity.